# Convert apache config to nginx equivalent for logs

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apache2

I have this custom log in apache

```
 SetEnvIFNoCase User-agent "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" skiplog
 LogFormat "%t \"%r\" %>s %O | client:%a | Local:%A | Host:%v | %H | %m | %P(pid) | TimeTaken:%T | %q |DataReceived:%I-Sent:%O-Total:%S | %l | %u | \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" mylog
 LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined_mylog
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log mylog env=!skiplog
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_org.log combined_mylog env=!skiplog
```

Basically i want to skip the log if user agent is `"ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"`

Now i have shifted to nginx and i am not sure how to use it in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nginx [`access_log`](https://nginx.org/r/access_log) directive accepts a parameter `if` which causes it to log only if the given condition is not false or an empty string.

So, you can set a variable and in the case that that user agent appears set the variable to 0. You can do this most easily in a [`map`](https://nginx.org/r/map):

```
map $http_user_agent $loggable {
    default                 1;
    ELB-HealthChecker/2.0   0;
}
```

Then you can modify `access_log` to check the variable:

```
    access_log /var/log/nginx/whatever-access.log log_format_name if=$loggable;
```

Comment: You didn't mention  map block needs to be outside server block :)

Comment: @Master Indeed. That's how it's documented in the documentation.